# Return true only if there is a absolute match

Tags: r

Is there a way to return true only if there is a absolute match.
Example

```
> total_years <- as.factor(c("2020","2021"))
> total_years
[1] 2020 2021
Levels: 2020 2021
> all(total_years %in% c("2017","2018","2019", "2020", "2021"))
[1] TRUE
```

It is returning True since 2020 and 2021 are present in total_years. But the output should be false, since there are other values (2017, 2018, 2019)

Basically it should return TRUE only if it also exists 2020 and 2021 only

Answer (score 1):

You can find the documentation with `?"%in%"`:

> returns a logical vector indicating if there is a match or not for its left operand.

Could also use `setequal()`.

```
setequal(total_years, c("2017","2018","2019", "2020", "2021"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply reverse the order of the arguments in the `%in%` statement, so you are asking whether each of the left hand arguments in the right hand arguments:

```
all(c("2017","2018","2019", "2020", "2021") %in% total_years)
[1] FALSE
```

and

```
> all( c("2020", "2021") %in% total_years)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Why this works and the other doesn't?

Comment: Because you are asking whether each of the left hand arguments in the right hand arguments, and since some of them are not, it will return ``FALSE``.